What's the fastest way to get "postcodes" for thousands of coordinates (latitudes & longitudes) in Python?

I have a dataset that contains 750,000 rows. I want to query each row and get the postcodes using the latitudes and longitudes.
Problem:
The code is executing very fast when I query like 100 rows, and it takes like 10min to query 1000 rows. But, when I try to query like 10,000 rows, it takes hours.
Question(s):
Is there any way I can speed up the querying so that the code will execute faster?
OR
Is there any new approach I can take to get a quicker and accurate result?
My code:
#new_df = green_taxi_fare_df.copy()[:20000]

from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

postcodes = []

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent = "app_name")

for index, row in new_df.iterrows():
    row_location = geolocator.reverse(f"{row['Pickup_latitude']}, {row['Pickup_longitude']}", timeout = 10)
    
    postcode = row_location.raw['address']['postcode'] if 'postcode' in row_location.raw['address'] else '00000'
    postcodes.append(postcode)
       
new_df['start_postcode'] = postcodes




Where is new_df defined?

You're importing folium but not using it in the code you provided. Is it possible your actual code looks quite different?

@Mast....."new_df" is a copy of some rows in the dataset(new_df = green_taxi_fare_df.copy()[:20000])

I've removed it, i used it for something different.

Since your problem is network-bound, consider employing thread-based parallelism. You could use a thread pool and submit each row separately, fitting thread count to your system specifics.

@STerliakov I'm not familiar with that, please can you point me to the right direction?

If you are restricted to finding zipcodes in the US then I would do this a completely different way.
You have 750,000 rows, i.e. longitude and latitude pairs and you want to map those to zip codes, but public data shows there are only 30-odd thousand zipcodes. Public data can map these to lat-long pairs (see https://gist.github.com/erichurst/7882666)
Then with that mapping you can design a function that can find the nearest neighbour to any lat-long pair and assign it the zipcode that corresponds to that point. This can all be done on your local computer with your static data.
This will avoid the slow network access and you you can potentially optimise the function in various different ways. I expect you should be able to get a lookup down to a few ms if not better, meaning completing the task for 750,000 rows should take maybe 20mins as a rough guess. If you can parallelise maybe it takes 1-2 mins?
Here is a very basic, completely un-optimised attempt that finds a zip from 35000 zips in 7ms:
import random

MAP = {}
for i in range(35000):
    MAP.update({i: (random.random(), random.random())})

def manhattan_distance(point, point2):
    return abs(point[0] - point2[0]) + abs(point[1] - point2[1])

def get_zip(lat, long):
    min_distance = 1e9
    nearest_key = -1
    for k, v in MAP.items():
        new_distance = manhatten_distance(v, (lat, long))
        if new_distance < min_distance:
            min_distance = new_distance
            nearest_key = k
    return nearest_key

import time
start = time.time()
key = get_zip(0.5, 0.5)
end = time.time()

print(f"one eval took: {end-start:.4f} seconds")
print(f"zipcode is '{key}'")

# one eval took: 0.0069 seconds
# zipcode is '28395'


Prefer the conventional spelling of "Manhattan". Please use from geopy.distance import great_circle for distance. As written the code claims that one unit North-South is same distance as one unit East-West, with errors near 04401 Bangor ME being worse than near 33101 Miami FL. But +1 anyway, since "local DB" is definitely on the right track.

Good point about the topographic distance function. There might be other consideration specific to zipcodes too that I am not aware of, i.e. the assumption here is that a data coordinate is the centre of the zipcode but zipcode boundaries may be more awkward. Anyway, no real knowledge of this so just something to consider if taking this further.
